# Symfony2 Ddeboer Data Import Bundle - OneToMany Reader, help needed

Tags: symfony, bundle, data-import

I used it with simple tables without any relationships, But I can't quite get it to work with the OneToMany documentation that the bundle provides in this link, [Ddeboer - documentation](https://github.com/ddeboer/data-import#onetomanyreader) .. So If anyone knows of any documentation or help, it would be much appreciated..

I have two classes with a one to many relationship, Team and Player:

> class Player extends BaseEntity
>   {

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Type(type="string")
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable = true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $team;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="2048k", groups={"Employee"})
 */
private $file; //For the excel file
```

Then class Team:

> class Team extends BaseEntity
>   {

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Type(type="string")
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable = true)
 */
private $name;
```

- I want the user to be able to attach an excel sheet for the Players, with headers:
  name and team name

Comment: Please add the code of your classes and what do you want to achieve